# Assembly access

Tags: c#, .net

If you have a assembly identity/namespace of `Library.Testing`.
Then you created another assembly with identity/namespace of `Library.Testing.One`
`Library.Testing.One` project references `Library.Testing`.

Why is it you have to use `using Library.Testing;` in your classes in `Library.Testing.One` to access anything in `Library.Testing`?

Example1:

```
using System;

namespace Library.Testing.One
{
    // 'Library.Testing' is a reference in this assembly
    public class foo : Library.Testing.BooBase
   {
   }
}
```

This does not work I get two exception

> Warning 1 Load of property
>   'RootNamespace' failed.  The string
>   for the root namespace must be a valid
>   identifier. Error 2 The type or
>   namespace name 'BooBase' does not
>   exist in the namespace
>   'Library.Testing.One.Library.Testing'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

Example2:

```
using System;
using Library.Testing;

namespace Library.Testing.One
{
    // 'Library.Testing' is a reference in this assembly
    public class foo : Library.Testing.BooBase
   {
   }
}
```

This works!

Comment: Reducing your original code to just two classes in two different assemblies does not reproduce the error. Do you perhaps have other classes in the Library.Testing.One assembly that have created an ambiguous namespace of "Library.Testing.One.Library.Testing"?

Comment: I wrote this example based on a class library I have created.  I recreated the project as I wrote it and I don't get the error.  The problem must be something else I will have to dig through the code.  Thank you for you time sorry if you fell I wasted it.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was a compact framework project and the directory the application was deploying in had an underscore.

Example:  Testing._

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "using" for `Library.Testing.One` does not automatically bring everything in `Library` and `Library.Testing` into scope. The fact that the namespaces appear to be hierarchical is probably what's leading to your confusion.

Think of, for example, adding `using System.Data.SqlClient` to a file. That doesn't automatically bring everything in `System` and `System.Data` into scope.

Comment: I would agree but 'Library.Testing.One' has a reference of 'Library.Testing'.  So I would think I would be in the clear but I am getting that strange error unless I add 'using Library.Testing.One'.